# High Pass Filter Design from Transfer Function

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, transfer-function, electronic-filters

I need to design an active high pass filter circuit that implements the following transfer function:

$$G(s)= 4.15\times\dfrac{s+530}{s+2200}$$

where, $K = 4.15$, Pole @ 2200 rad/s and Zero @ 530 rad/s.

I have already designed the non-inverting amplifier component of this circuit, using two resistors of value 1k and 4.15k. The issue I have is the passive component of the circuit and trying to control the poles and zeros of the transfer function. This is all I have attempted, I am completely stuck.

Comment: Well three points : One, have you considered the Electronics Stack and Two, What have you done so far? Three, is this homework?

Comment: Posted and Answered here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/402519/152903

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Can you show your non-inverting amplifier design?